# Repeat polygon marker line by interval: neighboring polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, symbology, markers

As you can see in the screenshot below, I use a polygon marker line with interval. If there are 2 neighboring polygons, the markers will be doubled - of course.

But I need to suppress this effect. Any ideas?

[image: example]

EDIT: In my case, the polygons are in the SAME layer.

Comment: 1. Merge polygons 2. Apply a marker line with an interval to it with no fill-in property. 3. Initial polygons use without a border/edge. 4. Put Merged styled layer over initial polygons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Taras's answer is almost there, but if you dissolve the polygons first, you will only get the outer boundary and none of the inner ones.

If you are OK with creating a separate layer, you can try the following:

1. Use Polygons to lines or Boundary geoprocessing tool on original layer
2. Dissolve the lines from step 1
3. Apply marker line style with no fill to the dissolved layer
4. Disable the stroke line/border for the original layer
5. Place the dissolved layer over the original layer.

Alternatively you can create a virtual layer with the following query:

```
SELECT ST_Union(ST_Boundary(geometry)) as geometry FROM polygon_layer
```

Alternatively, using a geometry generator symbology you can use the following expression to generate a line and style it as a marker line - the trick was to use `combine()` not `union()` to merge the geometries completely. However this can result in some strange marker placement near the intersection of multiple lines.

```
combine(collect(boundary($geometry)),collect(boundary($geometry)))
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Note this is also helpful when you don't want overlapping dashed lines.

Comment: p.s. dissolve ≠ merge =)

Comment: @Taras Do you mean "select features and merge" because that does the same thing as well, gets rid of the inner boundaries. I don't see any tool that does what you're describing with the name "merge" in the description.

Comment: I thought that author referring to two different layers, therefore IMHO applying `Merge Vector Layers` is fair enough.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe OP can clarify whether they are using two separate layers or adjacent polygons in the one layer.

Comment: you are right, this might be elucidated. But I thought when there was a single layer such problem should not exist because QGIS is smart enough.

Comment: OP has clarified they're polygons in the same layer. I've known this was a problem with adjacent polygons for a while as it would double up rendering dashed outlines, making it look like a single line (like in the Before pic in my answer). So thanks to OP for poking my brain as I've now solved one of my own problems as well.

Comment: Perfectly done !